# SSL connection between two Android devices

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, tcp

I am new to SSL. I need to implement SSL connection between two Android devices via TCP.
Is there any example how to do it? How can I create SSLServerSocket?

I tried to set property for default keystore, for using SSLServerSocket

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "my_keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

this doesn't help.

I'm able to create SSLServerSocket, but on accept() it fails with following exception:
"**SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites**"
Also I use certificate of a proper type on Android: BKS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698942/create-ssl-socket-on-android-with-self-signed-certificate etc.

Comment: @shkschneider Thanks for the reply. Actually this is an abstract class http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html;  I've tried to use http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html but without success. I receive an exception.

Comment: which exception? Please post what you tried below your question

Comment: What do you want to achieve (regarding security) using SSL? SSL is designed for servers with static DNS or IP address - in a peer-to-peer scenario it looses some of its security features.

Comment: @Robert Hi, I need to implement secure data exchange in local Wi-Fi network.

Comment: @Division_Bell: Static or dynamic scenario. What do you mean with "secure" - resistant to sniffing and/or resistant to Man.in-the-Middle attacks?

Comment: @Robert Static scenario. For example I scan for devices connected to Wi-Fi spot, choose one and send some data.

Comment: @Division_Bell That is only static if the devices establish the connection. The other way you it is very difficult to use SSL in a secure way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not different than using SSL sockets on any platform, refer to the JSSE reference. The only thing to watch out is that you need to have the phones on the same network (if local), and your carrier might be filtering/blocking inbound connections if on 3G, etc. Also keep in mind that mobile devices can change their IP when re-connecting, etc., so a fixed IP might not work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Have also one question. When I use SSLServerSocket.accept() I receive the exception "SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites". As I know, I need to load a certificate and initialize the SSLContext. How can it be done in Android?

Comment: Those system properties are not supported on Android. You need to load the keystore files in code. See the JSSE tutorial for the details.